# How many 1-10 number can be stored in one byte?

Tags: arrays

I have many 1-10 numbers. In C++, is it possible to store more than two in a single byte?

I believe it's possible to store at least 2: a char is from 0-255. This means we can store a number from 0-9 and one from 10-100.

a) Is it possible to store more than 2, with some kind of bit manipulation?

b) What's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: In principle yes since the smallest power of 2 bigger than 10 is 16 which is 2^4 and since a `char` is 8 bits you could store two single digits but why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Luka why do you think you need to save memory?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question like [musefan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/838807/musefan) commented you can do this if you do byte conversion yourself. For example if you have two number 4 and 10, then you can store as 0x4A, two numbers in a byte. More context might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if memory is not an issue, avoid it. Use signed or unsigned char to store a single value.

If you want to save memory (like transmission of data array over network or save file size), you can manipulate single bits of a byte using bit operators. For example, let's get values from 0 to 15 - it fits into 4 bits. Then

```
// values from 0 ot 15
unsigned char v1 = 1, v2 = 15;
// pack two values into one byte
unsigned char elem = (v1 << 4) + v2; // shift v1 to left and add v2

// unpack values
v1 = elem >> 4; // shift to right
v2 = elem & 0x0F; // clear higher 4 bits

// of course, you are going to use an array of elems
```

Comment: When you say "avoid it", is there a huge performance penalty, or a very small one?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you need a fast access (many computations with the numbers), then avoid it. If you need small memory (data packets, file storage), then these IO operations are slow, and it's worth to perform the compression.

Comment: @Luka the main reason to avoid it if you don't have memory constraints is that it needlessly complicates your code.

Answer (score 4):

There are 10 possible numbers from 1 to 10 (obvious, I know, but it must be said). A choice from 10 possible values requires log(10) / log(2) ~= 3.32 bits to encode. That means that the most you can store in 8 bits is two such choices.

But if you have a large number of them, you can store more than two per byte *in aggregate*. For example, in 32 bits you can store 9 numbers from 1 to 10 (requiring 29.9 bits), which is 2.25 per byte.

Comment: great point. so, if I have one 8 byte variable = 64 bits, how many can I store?

Comment: Also, in that sense, I can create a huge array of chars and store tons of them, right?

Comment: You can store 19 digits.

Comment: @Luka floor( 64 * log(2) / log(10) ) = 19

Comment: @Luka (Not coincidentally, 2^64 is a 20-digit number. But only 19 of those are useful, because the 10^19 place can only be 0 or 1).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking whether you can store 3 decimal digits, for example "7 and 5 and 8".

If so then the answer is, no: because to store 3 independent numbers you need to store any of 1000 values. One byte can store only 256 values.

The most compact/compressed storage format for your numbers is:

- Subtract 1 from each number to convert it from "1 to 10" to decimal digit "0 to 9"
- Combine the decimal digits and store them as an ordinary (unsigned) binary number

For example, "8 and 6 and 9" -> "7 and 5 and 8" -> "758" -> 0x256 -> 1001010110

Comment: re your last line I note that since the numbers are 1-10 you need to encode 10 as 0 in this storage method. Worth being explicit I figure.